# code blocks debugger not stoping

Tags: c++, debugging, codeblocks

I have code blocks 13.12 with borland 5.5 and mingw debugger. Everytime I debug, it debugs it completely without stopping at breakpoints or cursor (when pressed run to cursor). The debug log is:

```
Building to ensure sources are up-to-date
Selecting target: 
Debug
Adding source dir: G:\Copy_string\
Adding source dir: G:\Copy_string\
Adding file: G:\Copy_string\bin\Debug\Copy_string.exe
Changing directory to: G:/Copy_string/.
Set variable: PATH=.;C:\Borland\BCC55\Bin;C:\Borland\BCC55;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS                      
Client;C:\Windows\System32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\wbem;C:\Windows\System32\
WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\Program Files\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x86;C:\Program    
Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management   
Engine Components\IPT

[debug]Command-line: C:\CodeBlocks\MinGW\bin\gdb.exe -nx -fullname  -quiet  -args     
G:/Copy_string/bin/Debug/Copy_string.exe
[debug]Working dir : G:\Copy_string

Starting debugger: C:\CodeBlocks\MinGW\bin\gdb.exe -nx -fullname  -quiet  -args     
G:/Copy_string/bin/Debug/Copy_string.exe
done

[debug]> set prompt >>>>>>cb_gdb:

Registered new type: wxString
Registered new type: STL String
Registered new type: STL Vector
Setting breakpoints

[debug]Reading symbols from G:\Copy_string\bin\Debug\Copy_string.exe...(no debugging symbols   found)...done.
[debug](gdb) >>>>>>cb_gdb:
[debug]> show version

Reading symbols from G:\Copy_string\bin\Debug\Copy_string.exe...(no debugging symbols  found)...done.

[debug]GNU gdb (GDB) 7.5
[debug]Copyright (C) 2012 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
[debug]License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
[debug]This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
[debug]There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
[debug]and "show warranty" for details.
[debug]This GDB was configured as "i686-pc-mingw32".
 [debug]For bug reporting instructions, please see:
 [debug]<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
 [debug]>>>>>>cb_gdb:
 [debug]> set confirm off

 Debugger name and version: GNU gdb (GDB) 7.5

 [debug]>>>>>>cb_gdb:
 [debug]> set width 0
 [debug]>>>>>>cb_gdb:
 [debug]> set height 0
 [debug]>>>>>>cb_gdb:
 [debug]> set breakpoint pending on
 [debug]>>>>>>cb_gdb:
 [debug]> set print asm-demangle on
 [debug]>>>>>>cb_gdb:
 [debug]> set unwindonsignal on
 [debug]>>>>>>cb_gdb:
 [debug]> set print elements 0
 [debug]>>>>>>cb_gdb:
 [debug]> set new-console on
 [debug]>>>>>>cb_gdb:
 [debug]> set disassembly-flavor att
 [debug]>>>>>>cb_gdb:
 [debug]> catch throw
 [debug]Function "__cxa_throw" not defined.
 [debug]Catchpoint 1 (throw)
 [debug]>>>>>>cb_gdb:
 [debug]> source C:\CodeBlocks\share\codeblocks/scripts/stl-views-1.0.3.gdb
 [debug]>>>>>>cb_gdb:
 [debug]> set follow-fork-mode child
 [debug]>>>>>>cb_gdb:
 [debug]> directory G:/Copy_string/
 [debug]Source directories searched: G:/Copy_string;$cdir;$cwd
 [debug]>>>>>>cb_gdb:
 [debug]> run
 [debug]Starting program: G:\Copy_string\bin\Debug\Copy_string.exe 

 Child process PID: 3596

[debug][New Thread 3596.0x4e4]
[debug][Inferior 1 (process 3596) exited with code 020325214]
[debug]>>>>>>cb_gdb:

[Inferior 1 (process 3596) exited with code 020325214]

[debug]> quit

Debugger finished with status 0
`
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that 'Build->Select target' is [X] Debug. Then open the source program you want to debug and click on the line where you want the debugger to stop.

Lastly, use [Right Click]+[Run to cursor]. A yellow arrow should show besides the line number on your source code window.

Comment: i hav don everything but the problem is that it is debugging but all in one go..it is not pausing neither the yellow arrow is appearing

Answer (score 0):

This worked with me:

1. **choose debugger from setting.**

[image: debugger]

2. **select default**

[image: default]

3. **change the executable path to**
   C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\gdb.exe

[image: change path]

Comment: Please edit your answer to include the images directly instead of their links. Checkout https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help for formatting guides.